# How to configure GRUB to not set the filesystem as read-only at boot?

Tags: ubuntu

I am installing Ubuntu Base and I want to experiment with it so I don't want to install systemd..

My understanding is that Grub instructs init to mount the system as ro initially and then init sets it to rw...

How do I configure GRUB so that it doesn't cause init to mount the fs as ro ?

Comment: Actually, the linux kernel will mount as `rw` by default if not told otherwise, `grub` overrides this by passing `ro` on the kernel command line... and init will re-mount according to `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

You simply configure GRUB to supply the kernel boot option `rw` instead of the usual `ro`.

But if the root filesystem is initially mounted in read/write mode, you'll lose the chance to run a filesystem check on the root filesystem.

The purpose of initially mounting the root filesystem in read-only mode is to allow the filesystem checking tool to check the root filesystem without the risk of the kernel writing back some of the filesystem metadata it may have already cached at that point. If the boot-time check of the root filesystem needs to make any changes, the system boot-up scripts will usually automatically reboot the system right after the check is completed, to prevent kernel acting on "stale" data it may have in its disk cache.

On most filesystem types, you should never run a check on a filesystem that is already mounted in read/write mode.